# How to use a tpl.php file for a theme function

Tags: theming, authentication-authorization

I am using [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) which provides a theme function. You can use this theme function in a template.php file to control the mark up.

However, the code becomes quite unwieldy in template.php. Is there any way to modify the function so it can use a tpl.php file?

---

### More info

This is the function LoginToboggan provides:

```
function theme_lt_unified_login_page($variables) {

  $login_form = $variables['login_form'];
  $register_form = $variables['register_form'];
  $active_form = $variables['active_form'];
  $output = '';

  $output .= '<div class="toboggan-unified ' . $active_form . '">';

  // Create the initial message and links that people can click on.
  $output .= '<div id="login-message">' . t('You are not logged in.') . '</div>';
  $output .= '<div id="login-links">';
  $output .= l(t('I have an account'), 'user/login', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('login-link'), 'id' => 'login-link')));
  $output .= ' ';
  $output .= l(t('I want to create an account'), 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('login-link'), 'id' => 'register-link')));

  $output .= '</div>';

  // Add the login and registration forms in.
  $output .= '<div id="login-form">' . $login_form . '</div>';
  $output .= '<div id="register-form">' . $register_form . '</div>';

  $output .= '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a template file **lt-unified-login.tpl.php** in your theme directory and put this function inside **template.php** to override **theme_lt_unified_login_page** & return the HTML output of **lt-unified-login.tpl.php**.

```
function YOURTHEME_lt_unified_login_page($variables) {
  $template = drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME').'/lt-unified-login.tpl.php';
  return theme_render_template($template, $variables);
}
```

Comment: This would require to change the module, when it is not necessary.

Comment: You're correct. I was thinking theme_lt_unified_login_page was his own custom theme function. Can he override theme_lt_unified_login_page and use the solution above?

Comment: You can override any theme function and force them to use a template file. I cannot write an answer right now; I will do it, in the next 24 hours.